# CSS aligning text boxes with labels

Tags: html, css

My fiddle pretty much shows the problem. Trying to get the labels to be on the left side of each text box if anyone could help. http://jsfiddle.net/HC64Y/

```
<div id="boxalign2" class="boxalign2" >                 
    <label>Hospital*:</label><input class="rounded2" required title="Hospital is required!" name="MainHospital" type="text" />  
    <label>Title*:</label><input class="rounded2" name="MainTitle" type="text"/>            
    <label>Department*:</label> <input class="rounded2" name="MainDept" type="text"/>
</div>
```

css

```
input.rounded2 {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 4px 7px;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are making your inputs `inline-block`, but you are also floating them to the left.

If you remove the `float: left` and add `<br>` after each input, you will get the correct behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/A8es3/

To align the boxes, add a `div` wrapper around each label/input, make your label `inline-block` with a fixed width.  There are other ways to do this as well, but this is one way.

http://jsfiddle.net/A8es3/1/

As stolli mentioned, you can also simply use the `label` element as the wrapper:

http://jsfiddle.net/A8es3/2/

Comment: I'm trying to keep the text boxes aligned(as seen in my fiddle) which is how I got to my problem.

Comment: Great examples.  Very useful. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can give to your div `.boxalign2` and `label` fixed widths.

View the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/HC64Y/11/**

```
.boxalign2 {
  width:400px;
}

label {
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To ammend Jeff B's answer to get your result, simply give the  elements a width in your css

`label {width: 100px}`  where '100' is whatever value looks best for your layout.

Also, remember that the primary purpose of labels (as opposed to just div's or span's for labeling) is that labels act as a secondary click target for the control they are associated with.  Therefore, you can wrap your elements in the label tag (`<label><input /></label>`) or associate them by id (`<label for="foo"><input id="foo"/>`) and give the user much more to click, simply by clicking the label, they can toggle the control, focus the text input, whatever.  A big boon in usability for touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Centering a form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name">

        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email">

        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<style type="text/css">
    .form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 210px;
    }
    .form label{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
        float: left;
    }
    .form input{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/durtpwvx/